# Tex going below page bottom

Tags: tables

I have been writing documents in Latex for a while, but this never happened to me before. I have a page with some text, images (with subfloats) and a table, and what happens is that the page doesn't end where it should. In other words, some text and table go below the page limit. This seems somewhat related to the table itself, since everything goes back to normal if I remove the table. However, it's almost the same table format that I have everywhere else, I just modified the text inside it.

I have reported an image showing the issue and the code related to the table. I don't know if this can help, but I am using TexStudio with xelatex as compiler.

Any help would be appretiated, thank you.

[image: This is an image of the problem]

```
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{8pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{8pt}
\keepXColumns
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{SYSYSY}\hhline{===}
        & \textbf{Absolute error} & \textbf{Relative error}\\ \hline
        Position & 0.0794 km & 2.177 $\times 10^{-9}$ \\
        Velocity & 9.865 $\times 10^{-8} \frac{\text{km}}{\text{s}}$ & 1.199 $\times 10^{-8}$ \\
        \hhline{===}
        \caption{High eccentricity orbit maximum errors.}\label{tab:HighEccOrbit_Errors}
    \end{tabularx}  
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete but small [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that included the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Presumably you got a warning in the log, you should show the log message but also without a test file more or less impossible to say why this page break could not be found.

Comment: probably unrelated but the `\caption` should be after the `tabularx` not in it.

Comment: `2.177 $\times 10^{-9}$ ` gives a rather strange setting with the first part in text and the second part in math. In general this may mean a different font is used for the second part of the number.

Comment: For the numbers and their units, you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package. With this package, you can use `\SI{9.865 E-8}{\km\per\s}`. Also, is there really the need to stretch this table to be as wide as the textwidth? This just adds a lot of white space in the table and does not increase its readability. Probably a regular `\begin{tabular}{ccc}` works for you as well.